# Developing Old B&W Film

Tags: film, 35mm, developing

I have 10 roles of exposed b&w film (Kodak Plus-X (ISO 125) and Kodak Tri-X/Ilford XP1/HP5 (ISO 400) from the late-1970's/early 1980's which have been stored in a cool, dry basement.

Is there a chance there will be viable images on the roles when I get them developed?

Thanks, John

Answer (score 0):

It can be done probably best by "inspection" See if you can find a custom lab in your area or a keen amateur. If they are charging you  it should be expensive. Where are you located.

Comment: Do you mean `shouldn't`?

Comment: The `inspection` method is a bit more complex. You're not just inserting the film into a development tank and than roll the development tank for a few minutes. You also have to use some extra chemical (desensitizer) which is expensive.  So, I guess he really meant `should be expensive` :)

Comment: I live in Fredericksburg VA and have looked for a lab in Richmond VA; DC will next and then online unless someone has a lab they would recommend.

Comment: look  up colton  labs  some ware in new jersey  they it was written up in the New York Times  he is a fabulous printer  it will not be cheap Best David